# Definite integral of function inverse to a polynomial

Tags: calculus, integration

$f(x) = x+ x^3$

$g(y) = f^{-1}(x)$

$\int_2^{10} g(y) dy = $ ?

$\int_2^{10} g(y) dy =$ [$dy = df(x), dy = 1+3x^2$] = $\int_1^2 (1+3x^2)dx$ = [$x+x^3$] =$ 10 - 2 =8$

Am I right or I did a mistake? My friend told me that $dy = 1+(x^3)/3$

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=f(x)$ then $dy=f'(x)dx$ so

$$\int_2^{10}g(y)dy=\int_{g(2)}^{g(10)} xf'(x)dx=\int_1^{2}x(1+3x^2)dx=\left[\frac {x^2}2+\frac{3x^4}4\right]_1^2=\frac{51}4$$

Comment: It's almost like what I did, check it please, but why $x(1+3x^2)$?

Comment: We have $g(f(x))=x$ so you miss $x$ as a factor.

Comment: Why $g(f(x))=x$?

Comment: $g$ is the inverse of $f$ so $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Yes sir, but why it is equal to $x$?

Comment: As I explained $g\circ f(x)=\operatorname{id}(x)=x$.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @ChristianBlatter

Answer (score 1):

In the rectangle $[0,2]\times[0,10]$ of the $(x,y)$-plane draw the curve 
$$y=f(x)\quad(1\leq x\leq2),\qquad{\rm resp.}\qquad x=g(y)\quad(2\leq y\leq 10)\ .$$
By inspection of the figure one then sees that
$$\int_2^{10} g(y)\>dy=2\cdot10-1\cdot 2-\int_1^2 f(x)\>dx=18-\left.\left({x^2\over2}+{x^4\over4}\right)\right|_1^2={51\over4}\ .$$